# I am trying push a code to my remote repo but its taking me to someone else's repo. how do i fix it?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-push, repo

[image]
GIT push is trying to push my code to some one else's repository.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Git has something known as "remotes". These are the urls git is going to push the code to. When you execute `git remote -v` you will see all the remotes (The default is two, one for fetch (or pull) and one for push).

```
 $ git remote -v
 origin  https://github.com/kaffarell/prometheus.git (fetch)
 origin  https://github.com/kaffarell/prometheus.git (push)
 $
```

In the list you can see the remote name (origin) and the remote url. You can also add another url by executing `git remote add <name> <url>` and delete one by exeucting  `git remote remove <name>`. In your case, I would remove this remote and add the correct one.

Comment: ohmyz.sh? A man of culture I see